# Trigger to validate appointment capacity

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This is the table I have in MySQL workbench:
[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mvI1.jpg)

and i am trying to make a trigger that will throw an error message or alert if the appointments at a given data are more than 3;

here is the trigger I have
[TRIGGER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bVVs.jpg)

I get an syntax error somewhere on my IF statement i believe.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The select isn’t terminated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.